# Clear Text Signing using OpenSSL in C Code

Tags: c, openssl, sign, pkcs#7, smime

I am trying to sign a email message using OpenSSL. I want to perform Clear Text Signing on the email message.

I know I can do this using command prompt with the command:

```
openssl smime -sign -in hw.txt -text -out signed.msg -signer mycert.pem
```

But how do I do this using C Code?

This is what I am doing right now:

```
int flgs = PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_TEXT;
PKCS7 * p7 = PKCS7_sign(signCert, pKey, certs, bio, flgs);
if(p7 != NULL) {
    int res = PKCS7_final(p7, bio, flags);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "OpenSSLJni", "\nFinal result is: %d", res);
    FILE *outfile = fopen("/storage/sdcard0/sign_output.txt", "w");
    BIO* out = BIO_new_fp(outfile, BIO_NOCLOSE) ;// BIO_new_file(outfile, "");
    BIO_reset(bio);
    SMIME_write_PKCS7(out, p7, bio, flags);
    return true;
}
```

But I in the output file I am only getting the signature not both the body and signature.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it.

It was just a missing flag.

```
int flgs = PKCS7_STREAM | PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_BINARY ;
```

Added this flag and it started working perfectly.